# Esconder div, exibir apenas na home

Tags: javascript, html

Como faço para **ocultar/remover** o slider e o banner embaixo dele com JavaScript?
Preciso que ele fique somente na home, mas ele está repetindo em todos os departamentos do [site](http://www.adamaslux.com.br).

Comment: Boa tarde @lucas, a melhor forma de fazer é verificar como está o código e restringir diretamente por lá, usar javascript estará "solucionando" o seu problema mas apenas visualmente. Aconselho verificar a estrutura do código.

Comment: É muito mais sensato fazer o contrário. COLOCAR a div somente na home. Qualquer outra coisa é gambiarra.

Comment: Ta usando algum tipo de framework? tipo wordpress ou cakePHP ou algum tipo de loja pronta? Seria melhor você especificar mais sobre o seu problema para podermos ajudar... fazer algo em javascript para camuflar algo que você não quer mostrar além de ser uma gambiarra bem feia só piora o desempenho do seu site como também pode te trazer problemas futuros de manutenção

Comment: Por favor poste o trecho de código relevante aqui mesmo. O link não só pode não estar no ar no futuro, como provavelmente não exibirá mais o problema que você descreve. E o ideal aqui é que as perguntas e respostas ajudem também futuros visitantes com problemas similares, não apenas quem perguntou. Obrigado.

Comment: Nós usamos a plataforma de ecommerce Ciashop. Ela só permite que alteramos o header e o footer.

Comment: @lucas consegue alterar o header e o footer de cada página ou somente todas ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: @Sergio, de todas ao mesmo tempo.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode procurar um texto na URL que identifique que mudou de página, utilizando o método [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)  na propriedade [document.URL](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_url.asp).

```
// Se encontrar o texto "/Departamento?idExpandido=" na URL 
// (creio que seja o suficiente para identificar que não é mais a homepage)
if (document.URL.indexOf("/Departamento?idExpandido=") > -1) { 
    // esconde os botões
    $(".carousel-indicators").hide(); 
    // Mais comandos
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Seria interessante dizer o que seu código faz e em que ele ajuda a solucionar o problema, mesmo que a explicação seja óbvia hoje, ela poderá ajudar vários outros desenvolvedores

Comment: Obrigado pela dica!

Answer (score 2):

Esse tipo de re-design do lado do cliente (via JavaScript) não é uma boa solução. O melhor é conseguir alterar isso do lado do servidor.

Assumindo que isso não é possível, então tem de encontrar algo que distingua as páginas. Reparei que o background so menu não funciona, isso podia ser uma ajuda se estivesse a funcionar...

Assim a ideia que tive foi procurar por aquele texto que mostra em que página se está, **e que não tem na primeira página**.

O texto é `Início > Camisas > Manga 7/8`
Um seletor para ele seria: `$('a[title="Início"]')`

A ideia é ter este código que, no caso de não haver essa informação, esconde o slider.

```
if (!$('a[title="Início"]')) $('.imgBaFu').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Duas soluções para fazer o banner sumir quando clicar no menu.

Solução número 1:

```
$('#cssmenu').click(function(){
    $('.imgBaFu').hide();
});
```

Solução número 2:

```
(function($){
    $.getUrlVar = function(key){
    var result = new RegExp(key + "=([^&]*)", "i").exec(window.location.search);
    return result && unescape(result[1]) || "";
    };
})(jQuery);

var r = $.getUrlVar("idExpandido");

r != "" ? $('.imgBaFu').hide() : 0;
```

Executando isso no `ready` vai resolver seu problema, já testei com o FireBug no seu site.

Comment: Maison, na verdade eu queria que o banner (slider) e o banner abaixo aparecesse só na Home. No caso, ele aparece em todas as páginas do site.

Comment: @Caputo estou fornecendo a resposta sim, estou dando a solução que ele pediu, enconder o banner quando a pagina não estiver no home, é isso que ele quer, foi isso que eu entendi.   Na segunda proposta eu verifico se existe algum valor no parametro passado via url, se existir parametro nao é home, entao ele da o hide() no banner

Comment: Olá @MaisonSakamoto da forma que estava antes da edição estava tratando somente quando houvesse um click. A sua solução 2 sim, funciona sem o click e então pode ser uma resposta a **Esconder div, exibir apenas na home**. Vou remover o comentario anterior

Comment: Isso mesmo, @MaisonSakamoto!! No caso eu queria que o segundo banner também sumisse. Mas já ajudou MUITO. Valeu galera.